# Return Users ordered by followers Instagram API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, instagram, instagram-api

I have an issue, I want to get the biggest accounts in Instagram using the API for ruby. When I said "biggest", I meant the accounts ordered by the amount of followers.

I found the service `/search`, but I don't know how to make the query. It seems that it's only to search by username.

Any idea or workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as Instragrams documentation goes this is not possible: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search

From what I can see you can only search by username and I don't see any other way to add parameters. So unless there is an unknown hidden param I don't think this is possible.

If you have a specific user you can see how many users follow that user here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_follows but you would need an access token for that user.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Yes I know, but I need the biggest account order by followers's account. So I have to request for each user, I have to find other way to order the list of users that the API returns. 
Also you don't need the access token, check the link below:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users
But any way, thank you :D